# List of unique characters in a column

Tags: r, string

I am trying to figure out how to extract all the unique characters from a certain column. For example, if one of my column has the following rows,

```
june  
july&  
august%
```

then I would like r to give me the list of all the unique characters, i.e,

`junely&agst%`

How can this be done in R?

Comment: unique(df$column)

Comment: @Dr.Flow that would just return all values from the sample data...

Comment: I think you mean special characters?

Comment: Including special characters yes. But is there a way to seprate just special characters?

Comment: aha, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the column values at each character and paste only unique characters.

```
x <- c('june', 'july&', 'august%')
paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, ''))), collapse = "")
#[1] "junely&agst%"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a Tidy approach will be useful:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

# input
x <- c("june", "july&", "august%")
expected <- "junely&agst%"


# modify
actual <- x %>% str_split(pattern = "") %>% flatten_chr %>% unique %>% paste0(collapse = "")


# validate
stopifnot(actual == expected)
```